# Программное моделирование чисел с плавающей точкой и функция itoa

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

string int2bin8(unsigned char num)
{
char charArr[9];
itoa(num, charArr, 2);
string res(charArr);
res.insert(0, 8 - res.size(), '0');
return res;
}

string int2bin24(unsigned int num)
{
char charArr[33];
itoa(num, charArr, 2);
string res(charArr);
res.insert(0, 32 - res.size(), '0');
return res;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
double iA, iB;
cout << "Dilene: ";
cin >> iA;
if (iA < 0)
    iA *= -1;
cout << "Dilnuk: ";
cin >> iB;
if (iB < 0)
    iB *= -1;

bool znakA = iA < 0, znakB = iB < 0;

int oA = 0, oB = 0;
if (iA >= 2)
    while (iA >= 2)
    {
        iA /= 2;
        oA++;
    }
else if (iA < 1)
    while (iA < 1)
    {
        iA *= 2;
        oA--;
    }
if (iB >= 2)
    while (iB >= 2)
    {
        iB /= 2;
        oB++;
    }
else if (iB < 1)
    while (iB < 1)
    {
        iB *= 2;
        oB--;
    }

int orR = oA - oB;

string bin_A = "", bin_B = "";
double temp = iA - (int)iA;
for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
{
    temp *= 2;
    bin_A += to_string((int)temp);
    temp -= (int)temp;
}
temp = iB - (int)iB;
for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
{
    temp *= 2;
    bin_B += to_string((int)temp);
    temp -= (int)temp;
}

cout << "    A: " << 1 << " " << int2bin8(oA + 127) << " " << bin_A << endl;
cout << "    B: " << 0 << " " << int2bin8(oB + 127) << " " << bin_B << endl;
cout << endl;

unsigned long long A, B, R;
A = stoi("1" + bin_A, nullptr, 2);
B = stoi("1" + bin_B, nullptr, 2);
R = 0;

//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
cout << "Zsuv dilnuka do spivpadannya starshuh cufer\n";

int dilene_d = 0, dilnik_d = 0;
while (A >> dilene_d != 0)
    dilene_d++;
while (B >> dilnik_d != 0)
    dilnik_d++;
int n = dilene_d - dilnik_d;
B = B << n;
n++;

R = 0;

cout << "    Deline:\n    " << int2bin24(A) << "\n    Dilnuk:\n    " << int2bin24(B) << "\n    Chastka:\n    " << int2bin24(R) << endl;

while (n > 0)
{
    cout << "Porivnyannya:\n";
    A -= B;
    R *= 2;
    if ((long long)A >= 0)
        R++;
    cout << "    Dilene:\n    " << int2bin24(A) << "\n    Dilnuk:\n    " << int2bin24(B) << "\n    Chastka:\n    " << int2bin24(R) << endl;
    if ((long long)A < 0)
    {
        cout << "Vidnovlennya zalushky:\n";
        A += B;
        cout << "    Dilene:\n    " << int2bin24(A) << "\n    Dilnuk:\n    " << int2bin24(B) << "\n    Chastka:\n    " << int2bin24(R) << endl;
    }
    n--;
    if (n <= 0)
        break;
    cout << "Zsuv dilnuka:\n";
    B /= 2;
    cout << "    Dilene:\n    " << int2bin24(A) << "\n    Dilnuk:\n    " << int2bin24(B) << "\n    Chastka:\n    " << int2bin24(R) << endl;
}
//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

while (R < 8388608)
{
    cout << "Porivnyannya:\n";
    A *= 2;
    R *= 2;
    A -= B;
    if ((long long)A >= 0)
        R++;
    cout << "    Dilene:\n    " << int2bin24(A) << "\n    Dilnuk:\n    " << int2bin24(B) << "\n    Chastka:\n    " << int2bin24(R) << endl;
    if ((long long)A < 0)
    {
        cout << "Vidnovlennya zalushky:\n";
        A += B;
        cout << "    Dilene:\n    " << int2bin24(A) << "\n    Dilnuk:\n    " << int2bin24(B) << "\n    Chastka:\n    " << int2bin24(R) << endl;
    }
}

double res2show = R / pow(2, 23);

if (res2show * pow(2, orR) != (iA * pow(2, oA))*(iB * pow(2, oB)))
{
    orR--;
}

res2show *= pow(2, orR);
cout << "    C= -" << res2show << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Как заменить в данном коде функцию `itoa()`?Сам код должен делить число с плавающей точкой.

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно следующее

```
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

//...

unsigned char c = 15;
std::bitset<32> b(c);
std::string res = b.to_string();
std::cout << res << std::endl;
```

Вывод на консоль этого фрагмента кода будет следующим

```
00000000000000000000000000001111
```

Например, функция `int2bin8` может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
std::string int2bin8(unsigned char num)
{
    std::bitset<8> b(num);

    return b.to_string();
}
```

Или даже можете записать в одну строчку

```
std::string int2bin8(unsigned char num)
{
    return std::bitset<8>(num).to_string();
}
```